# fast way to make index prefix with an alphabet

Tags: pandas

Is there a fast way to make the index from a1..a111? now it is just 1..111.

```
   fruit = pd.Series(['aa'] * 50 + ['bb'] * 50 + [None] * 10, name='fruit', index=range(1,111))
```

Answer (score 3):

use `rename_axis`

```
fruit.rename_axis('a{}'.format)

a1        aa
a2        aa
a3        aa
a4        aa
a5        aa
a6        aa
a7        aa
a8        aa
a9        aa
a10       aa
a11       aa
a12       aa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension`:

```
fruit = pd.Series(['aa'] * 50 + ['bb'] * 50 + [None] * 10, name='fruit',
                  index=['a'+ str(i) for i in range(1,111)])

print (fruit)
a1        aa
a2        aa
a3        aa
a4        aa
a5        aa
a6        aa
a7        aa
a8        aa
a9        aa
...
...
```

Another faster solution is convert `index` values to `string` and add `a`:

```
fruit = pd.Series(['aa'] * 50 + ['bb'] * 50 + [None] * 10, name='fruit', index=range(1,111))
fruit.index = 'a' + fruit.index.astype(str)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [86]: %timeit pd.Series(['aa'] * 50000 + ['bb'] * 50000 + [None] * 10000, name='fruit', index=['a'+ str(i) for i in range(1,110001)])
10 loops, best of 3: 76 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit pd.Series(['aa'] * 50000 + ['bb'] * 50000 + [None] * 10000, name='fruit', index=range(1,110001)).rename_axis('a{}'.format)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.9 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit jez()
10 loops, best of 3: 46.5 ms per loop
```